# jQuery: check if scrolled above one element and below another

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I'm trying to code a single-page website so that when the user scrolls to certain sections of the page, the navigation changes in response. I'm using this code to check when the user scrolls to an element:

```
if($(window).scrollTop()>=$('#element1').position().top){
   function...
}
```

The code works properly, but stops if I try to compare two different elements.

```
if($(window).scrollTop()>=$('#element1').position().top && 
$(window).scrollTop()<$('#element2').position().top){
    function...
}
```

The or (||) property does work, but I'm trying to change it based on the section they're in. What do I need to change to make this work properly?

Comment: I can't see any problem .. anyway you can create demo/snippet with relative html.css.js code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`scrollTop()` is relative to the window, but `position().top` is relative to offset parent.

You should use [$.offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) instead of [$.position()](https://api.jquery.com/position/) here.

```
if($(window).scrollTop() >= $('#element1').offset().top && 
$(window).scrollTop() < $('#element2').offset().top){
    function...
}
```